# Monkey-patching database adapter in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using PosgreSQL adapter to connect to Vertica database which is mostly compatible with PostgreSQL but doesn't support options like client_min_messages (which are still passed to `PGconn.connect` despite not being present in `database.yml`). I've made a quick and dirty monkey patch for `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter` but the problem is that I guess everything in AR in lazy loaded and the original file is read after my patch.

If I add `require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'` at the top of the monkey patch then ActiveRecord tries to establish connection and fails. Is it possible to alter this behavior to make the monkey patch work or should I just write a full-fledged connection adapter?

Comment: Do you have the fully module you used to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi @synapse ,  Facing same issue with Rails3 after upgrading postgres to 12 version. Can you please tell how did you solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hook your code to railties initialization. Including sample from my gem [multi_config](http://shadabahmed.com/blog/2012/09/18/introducing-multiconfig-gem-for-activerecord):

```
module <YourModule>
  # Railtie subclass for the gem/plugin
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie

    # Railtie initializer method
    initializer '<your_plugin>.active_record' do

      # When active_record is loaded, only then run this.
      ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
        # Hook your code here. For .e.g. 
        ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, <YourPluginModule>)
      end
    end
  end
end
```